# convertValue issue with Jackson - alternative?

Tags: java, jackson

I'm trying to get my head around the `convertValue` method of *Jackson*. Initially I thought it would be somewhat equivalent to the `Gson#fromJson` method but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Here's the problem:

```
// Map<String, Object> map = ...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyPojo pojo = mapper.convertValue(map.get(key), MyPojo.class);
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> m : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("k=" + m.getKey() + "    v=" + m.getValue());
}
pojo.name = "Banana";
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> m : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("k=" + m.getKey() + "    v=" + m.getValue());
}
```

**Output**

```
k=66e8c013   v=MyPojo{name='Apple'} 
k=66e8c013   v=MyPojo{name='Banana'}
```

*Note: Code and output has been stripped down to the relevant part*

So, if I modify my *pojo* object, it's also getting changed in the original `Map`. For me it seems like Jackson doesn't call "new MyPojo()" internally and set the values for each found variable afterwards.

What can I do to prevent this? Is there an alternative method? Do I need to create a copy constructor in order to get a truly new object without references to the values in the Map?
Additionally it would be cool if someone could tell me what `convertValue` actually does.

Comment: So, you're trying to convert a MyPojo to MyPojo? Jackson won't do anything when you do that: it will just return the original MyPojo, because there is no need to convert anything.

Comment: The source is always your best source for what code does.

Comment: @JBNizet Not necessarily. Often times it's a `LinkedHashMap` and in this case the error didn't occur. Though looking at the debugger you're right in this special case - so thanks.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I don't know why you've closed this as a duplicate? I haven't asked *"how to clone an object"* - I'm totally aware of my options. Initially I've tried to understand what's happening in my code. So closing doesn't seem appropriate - no offense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the code of `convertValue`, you find

```
    if (targetType != Object.class
            && !toValueType.hasGenericTypes()
            && targetType.isAssignableFrom(fromValue.getClass())) {
        return fromValue;
    }
```

So in your case if `map.get(key)` is of type `MyPojo`, the `convertValue()` method indeed returns the reference to your input. This explains, why the value in the map changes when you change the 'converted' object.

Now your question can be deduced to how to clone an object, which is a complicated topic in general.

- If you want safe deep copy, you can serialize and deserialize the object. This procedure, however, gives bad performance.
- You could implement the `clone()` method and mark the class `Cloneable`, which is a rather common solution and gives you control and good performance.
- You can also look into Apache Commons BeanUtils which has the `cloneBean()` method which uses getters and setters to clone the properties of the object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the source code snippet. I do understand the issue much better now.